# Ubuntu Crash after watching long youtube videos

Tags: 20.04, crash, youtube

I have experienced a confusing problem using a quite newly installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS.

When using Ubuntu normally everything works fine. As soon as I have a long youtube video (<30 mins) in Firefox playing - somewhen during the playtime of the video the Ubuntu UI will freeze, the audio will play a few seconds longer, before all goes black and I am left alone with my mouse cursor for a few seconds before this error message is displayed:

```
[10752.211584] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): __ext4_find_entry_1535: inode #31983115 comm gdm-session-wor: reading directory Iblock 0

[10752.211654] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block, lost sync page write

[10752.211688] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): I/O error while writing superblock
```

Interestingly this error appeared on 2 different SSDs (one old, one new) using a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the official page for installation - no custom installation, just the standard installation procedure.

As I have found no solution to a similar issue here or elsewhere on the internet, I´m looking here for help!

Comment: Hello. Can you describe your computer? How much ram do you have? can you post the output of "free -h"?. My experience on this is RAM and swap memory tunning.

Comment: Your trace clearly shows, that your hardware (sda2 in this case) has errors. Try `fsck` (sda2 must be unmounted) to fix it. If no broken inodes are found, the problem lies deeper

Comment: @kanehekili I assume I have to apply this command from the live usb system, as sda2 is my main partition for ubuntu - or did i do something wrong?

Comment: Well. It is not ram nor swap. that points to the disk activity as you trace says, but the estrange thing is that you say happen on two different ssd drives. Have you tried the same on another browser?

Comment: @jpbrain , I have the following system: Ryzen 3900x MSI MPG MoBo Vega 56 GPU 32 GB of RAM 2 monitors attached via gpu and one via docking station

that is the response to the 'free -h' command total occupied free shared inter available memory: 31Gi 2.3Gi 27Gi 67Mi 2.0Gi 28Gi swap: 2.0Gi 0B 2.0Gi

Comment: @jpbrain yes one drive is actually a brand new Samsung 860 SSD, which I sector tested before installing Ubuntu on it.
I will test this on Chrome too - maybe then it'll stop happening...

Comment: are the drives ssd or nvme?  to do the check "fsck", you can use a bootable pendrive. Also you can install nvme-cli (for nvme) and gsmartcontrol (ssd) to know more about the drives.